# CakePHP 3 & JSON response - Formatting response data linked with other tables

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables with their attributes:

> **Sessions**

- id
- staff_id

> **Staff**

- id
- firstname
- lastname

By clicking a link, I trigger my JavaScript code to open up a modal, and an AJAX call is sent to retrieve data in JSON format. I then use the JSON response to populate my modal.

The link that triggers the JavaScript is this:

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'popup', $session->id], ['class' => 'view', 'data-id' => $session->id]) ?>
```

This is an action from a table on a CakePHP 3 View. $session->id is decided based on which row of data the link is clicked. Popup is an empty CakePHP 3 function that just facilitates the JavaScript working and the modal opening up.

The JavaScript which triggers the modal is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.view').click(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var sessionId = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $('#viewModal').modal('show');
            $.ajax({
                url:"localhost/project/sessions/details/"+sessionId+".json",
                type:'POST',
                success:function(res) {
                    if(res) {
                        document.getElementById("prstaff").innerHTML = res.staff_id;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The details function from my CakePHP 3 SessionsController is this, which retrieves the relevant data for the $session->id that was obtained earlier:

```
public function details($id = null)
    {
        $details = $this->Sessions->get($id);
        $this->set(array(
            'output' => $details,
            '_serialize' => 'output',
            '_jsonp' => true
        ));
    }
```

This is my modal in full that then opens up:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="viewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="viewModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="viewModalLabel">Session Details</h3>
                <br>
                <table class="vertical table col-sm-2">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Staff Name:</th>
                        <td id="prstaff"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However the end result would just be:

**Staff Name:** 2 (or whatever foreign key is fetched)

This is not very meaningful. I could do another AJAX call for the Staff table, but I don't know how to link it to the first AJAX call so that when I want to populate the modal, I can actually put in meaningful data (eg. John Smith instead of foreign key 2).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you requesting JS via AJAX, then execute another query to retrieve JSON and then want to put this into the modal? This is weird and not necessary. If I understood this correctly at all.

1. Call the action and return the whole HTML content for the modal directly and let Cake render the data into the template, server side. This is just one AJAX call.
2. Have a template `<script type="html/template" id="model-template">conten here</script>`, on click do the AJAX call and return JSON and use to replace the placeholders `{{somevar}}` in your template and put the result in your modal. This is just one AJAX call as well. You can use [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) for easy template parsing, it's really small.

I personally prefer to work with JSON responses and filling templates.

Comment: I'm rather confused by how to go about doing this - should I be keeping my AJAX call where it is, and just change some of the elements inside it or should I be moving it and doing it later? I'm not entirely sure which parts I'm meant to change either.

Comment: Never mind, I got it working. Just changed $details in the details function to contain the other tables and then those tables were included as objects in the response to be used.